# User-Friendly PHP Error Message

Tags: php, error-handling

PHP is famous for displaying ugly error messages, though they are useful at times. I know I can hide error messages with

```
error_reporting(0);
```

That's fine, but it leaves the user completely in the dark as to what is going on. The page has stopped working and they don't know why. How can I display a simple message along the lines of "Sorry, there is an error. Please send an e-mail to the webmaster"?

It would be the same message for all errors, and I'm thinking of maybe popping up a javascript alert, but open to any other ideas.

Comment: You can create your own error handler using `set_error_handler`.

Comment: Try to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Implement an error and exception handler

You need to write a custom error handler like this. As you can see at the bottom, I am introducing a **`FATAL`** error. Here PHP does not spit any ugly error messages as you have quoted. It would just print `Some Error Occured. Please Try Later.`

```
<?php

set_error_handler( "log_error" );
set_exception_handler( "log_exception" );
function log_error( $num, $str, $file, $line, $context = null )
{

    log_exception( new ErrorException( $str, 0, $num, $file, $line ) );
}

function log_exception( Exception $e )
{
    http_response_code(500);
    log_error($e);
    echo "Some Error Occured. Please Try Later.";
    exit();
}

error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once("texsss.php");// I am doing a FATAL Error here
```

Comment: That looks good. Just one problem: the error doesn't show up in the normal error log. (It works if I comment out the custom error handler.) Is it logging it somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

There are some rules that should apply to production servers:

1. Never show them the original PHP error message! Set `display_errors = off`.
2. Log those errors. Set `log_errors = on` and define a valid log target in `error_log`.
3. Monitor the error log, and act upon it. :)

The handling of errors to the user side has been sufficiently answered by the others.

Comment: I can't claim to have always obeyed those rules in the past, but I intend to from now on. That's why I asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can write custom error handler that does it

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Answer (score 1):

This is typically done via Exceptions. If something goes awry, you'd throw an Exception and then "handle it" with an [exception handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php).

```
function exception_handler($exception) {
  echo "Oops! Something went wrong! We're looking into it!";
}

set_exception_handler('exception_handler');

throw new Exception('Uncaught Exception');
```

You can also catch a number of fatal errors by using [register_shutdown_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php).

[set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) might also tickle your fancy.

Answer (score 0):

User custom error handling [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)

and exception handler [set_exception_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php)

and there you can do what ever you like.